# ActiveRecord to use mysql named pipes on windows

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, named-pipes

Is it possible to connect from ruby/ActiveRecord to a mysql database over named pipes.
OS is Windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a few tries and looking at my .net connect calls i finally got it working.

I am using activerecord in a standalone script.

Here the call that works:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter => "mysql",
    :host => ".",
    :username => "root", 
    :password => "root", 
    :database => "test",
    :socket => "mysql_test")
```

Please note that by default the configuration tool that comes with mysql server configures a socket called "mysql". I have changed that to mysql_test to verify that indeed i am going over the named pipe.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working

Ruby version: 1.9.1
Mysql version: 5.0

code written was:

```
    require "rubygems"
    require "active_record"
    puts "1"
    class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
        puts "2"
        establish_connection(
                :adapter => "mysql",
                :host => "localhost",
                :username => "root",
                :password => "root@123",
                :database => "TrafficTracker"
            )
    end
    puts "3"
    traffic_source = Source.find(1)
    puts "4"
    puts traffic_source.source_name
```

Above code prints till 3 and breaks at Source.find(1) with error:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mysql.rb:1019:in `read': Packets out of order: 0<>  (RuntimeError)
>
>   from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mysql.rb:444:in`read'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mysql.rb:110:in `real_connect'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:600:in`connect'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:164:in `initialize'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:36:in`new'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:36:in `mysql_connection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:228:in`new_connection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `checkout_new_connection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in`block (2 levels) in c
>   heckout'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:186:in `loop'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:186:in`block in checkout'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize' 
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in`checkout'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:93:in `connection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:316:in`retrieve_connection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in `retrieve_conn
>   ection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in`connection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/base.rb:679:in `columns'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:284:in`attributes_from_column_definition'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:62:in `attributes_from_column_definition'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1394:in`initialize'
>           from C:/WorkspaceGunjan/TrafficTracker/TrafficTracker/TestProject/RubyPrograms/RubyPrograms/AccessTrafficTracker.rb:22:in `new'
>           from C:/WorkspaceGunjan/TrafficTracker/TrafficTracker/TestProject/RubyPrograms/RubyPrograms/AccessTrafficTracker.rb:22:in`'
>   C:\WorkspaceGunjan\TrafficTracker\TrafficTracker\TestProject\RubyPrograms\RubyPrograms>
>   C:\WorkspaceGunjan\TrafficTracker\TrafficTracker\TestProject\RubyPrograms\RubyPrograms>
>   C:\WorkspaceGunjan\TrafficTracker\TrafficTracker\TestProject\RubyPrograms\RubyPrograms>

Comment: are you on windows?
try "." as host

Comment: Tx memical, but it didn't work. Finally, after putting all my efforts with MySql and Postgresql, I am able to make successful connection with MySql.
Find details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888740/mysql-adapter-activerecord-in-ruby-throwing-packets-out-of-order/5148930#5148930