# Mysql adapter ActiveRecord in Ruby throwing: 'Packets out of order'

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

Ruby version: 1.9.1
Mysql version: 5.0

code written was:

```
    require "rubygems"
    require "active_record"
    puts "1"
    class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
        puts "2"
        establish_connection(
                :adapter => "mysql",
                :host => "localhost",
                :username => "root",
                :password => "root@123",
                :database => "TrafficTracker"
            )
    end
    puts "3"
    traffic_source = Source.find(1)
    puts "4"
    puts traffic_source.source_name
```

Above code prints till 3 and breaks at Source.find(1) with error:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mysql.rb:1019:in `read': Packets out of order: 0<>  (RuntimeError)
>
>   from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mysql.rb:444:in`read'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mysql.rb:110:in `real_connect'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:600:in`connect'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:164:in `initialize'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:36:in`new'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:36:in `mysql_connection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:228:in`new_connection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:236:in `checkout_new_connection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:190:in`block (2 levels) in c
>   heckout'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:186:in `loop'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:186:in`block in checkout'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize' 
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in`checkout'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:93:in `connection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:316:in`retrieve_connection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in `retrieve_conn
>   ection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in`connection'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_reco
>   rd/base.rb:679:in `columns'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:284:in`attributes_from_column_definition'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:62:in `attributes_from_column_definition'
>           from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1394:in`initialize'
>           from C:/WorkspaceGunjan/TrafficTracker/TrafficTracker/TestProject/RubyPrograms/RubyPrograms/AccessTrafficTracker.rb:22:in `new'
>           from C:/WorkspaceGunjan/TrafficTracker/TrafficTracker/TestProject/RubyPrograms/RubyPrograms/AccessTrafficTracker.rb:22:in`'
>   C:\WorkspaceGunjan\TrafficTracker\TrafficTracker\TestProject\RubyPrograms\RubyPrograms>
>   C:\WorkspaceGunjan\TrafficTracker\TrafficTracker\TestProject\RubyPrograms\RubyPrograms>
>   C:\WorkspaceGunjan\TrafficTracker\TrafficTracker\TestProject\RubyPrograms\RubyPrograms>

after analyzing more, i found problem with mysql.rb in \Ruby\lib\ruby\1.9.1
Method creating problem is:

```
def read()
      buf = []
      len = nil
      @sock.sync = false
      while len == nil or len == MAX_PACKET_LENGTH do
    a = @sock.read(4)
    len = a[0]+a[1]*256+a[2]*256*256
    pkt_nr = a[3]
    if @pkt_nr != pkt_nr then
      raise "Packets out of order: #{@pkt_nr}<>#{pkt_nr}"   #Exception raised at line number 1019
    end
    @pkt_nr = @pkt_nr + 1 & 0xff
    buf << @sock.read(len)
      end
      @sock.sync = true
      buf.join
    end
```

Comment: [A 
5.0.27-community-nt G   HP:n?.f8 ,?              'WabH"lzE(6w     ]  This (in []) is the Resoponse from socket of mysql. This might help in answering the question

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after putting all my efforts with MySql and Postgresql, I am able to make successful connection with MySql.
Working set involves:
Ruby Version: 1.87
MySql Version: 5.5
To work with ActiveRecord, one need to have the adapter installed. On command prompt, write:
gem install mysql2.

Code to build successful connection of MySql database with Ruby under the layer of ActiveRecord:

```
require "rubygems"
require "active_record"
class Source < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "sources"
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
        :adapter => "mysql2",
        :host => "localhost",
        :username => "test",
        :password => "test",
        :port => 3306,
        :database => "TestDB",
        :socket => "mysql"
    )
end
source = Source.find(:first, :conditions => [ "source_id = ?", 2 ])
puts source.source_name
```

*Note: Adapter used is mysql2 and not mysql*